# Binding multiple rows of results from mysqli prepared statement into multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a mysql query that fetches a number of rows from the database and I want to bind those results into a multidimensional array.

```
$sample = array();
$samples = array();
//bind results into $sample array
$stmt->bind_result($sample['id'], $sample['name'], $sample['image_path'],
    $sample['main_text'], $sample['nose'], $sample['palate'], $sample['finish'],
    $sample['sample_price'], $sample['retail_price'], $sample['retail_url']);
//fetch each row of results and push the resultant array into the $samples array
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $samples[] = $sample;
}
```

Here's a pseudo-code instantiation of what I'm hoping the above would achieve:

```
$samples = array(
0 => array(
    "id" => the item's id
    "name" => the item's name
    "image_path" => the item's image pgae
    "main_text" => the second item's main text
    "nose" => etc
    "finish" => etc
    "palate" => etc
    "sample_price" => etc
    "retail_url" => etc
1 => array(
    "id" => the second item's id
    "name" => the second item's name
    "image_path" => the second item's image page
    "main_text" => the second item's main text
    "nose" => etc
    "finish" => etc
    "palate" => etc
    "sample_price" => etc
    "retail_url" => etc
```

Instead, I'm ending up with an multidimensional array full of identical items. More specifically, if I step through the code:

1. The first item goes on the list fine
2. The second item goes onto the array and the first item becomes a duplicate of the second
3. The third item goes onto the array and the first and second items become a duplicate of the third
   etc.

My assumption would be that `$sample` is somehow being pushed onto the array by reference, but that doesn't make sense to me as php assigns arrays by value.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**Update**: I am aware of the get_result() function. Unfortunately, that only works if the mysqli extension was compiled using the MySQL native driver - this is something that is pretty difficult to guarantee.

Comment: Have you check my update?

Comment: @Alex yes, I have just done so. It works great, thank you :). Out of interest, I was wondering if you could tell me why my original code didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$samples = $result->fetchAll(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**UPDATE**

```
$stmt->bind_result($r_id, $r_name, $r_image_path,
    $r_main_text, $r_nose, $r_palate, $r_finish,
    $r_sample_price, $r_retail_price, $r_retail_url);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $samples[] = array('is'=>$r_id, 
           'name'=>$r_name, 
           'image_path'=>$r_image_path,
           'main_text'=>$r_main_text, 
           'rose'=>$r_nose, 
           'palate'=>$r_palate, 
           'finish'=>$r_finish,
           'sample_price'=>$r_sample_price, 
           'retail_price'=>$r_retail_price, 
           'retail_url'=>$r_retail_url);
}
```

Comment: I believe that only works if the mysqli extension was compiled to use the MySQL Native Driver - which is something that is almost impossible to guarantee?

Comment: That works! Awesome, thank you. Out of interest, I was wondering what I did wrong in my original code?

Comment: you cant bind_result with elements of array, that must be named variables